# How to use useState in a child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm not sure why I can't use my pass on useState from Parent component `<AppMain />` to the child component `<GroupPage />` and `<CreateGroupForm />`

What I'm trying to do:

I'm working on an update functionality, where on clicking the edit button in `<GroupPage />`, I want the content of GroupPage to fill on the form fields of `<CreateGroupForm />`. So for that, I have created states currentId and setCurrentId in `<AppMain />` since it's the parent component of both, and I can pass on these to its child components assuming they both share the states.

```
const AppMain = () => {

    const [ currentId, setCurrentId ] = useState(null)

    return (
        <div>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/groupMain" exact> <GroupMain /> </Route>
                    <Route path="/groupMain/:id" exact> <GroupPage setCurrentId={setCurrentId} /> </Route>
                    <Route path="/createGroup" exact> <CreateGroupForm currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} /> </Route>
                </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AppMain
```

```
const GroupPage = ({setCurrentId}) => {

    const { group } = useSelector((state) => state.groups)
        
    // the reason for this condition is to prevent rendering something before data is actually fetched
    if(!group) return null
    
    return (
              <div>
                   <EditButton onClick= {() => {
                    setCurrentId(group._id)
                    history.push(`/createGroup/`)
               }} />
                   <h1>{group.groupName}</h1>
              </div>
     )
}

export default GroupPage
```

Now when clicking on the edit button of `<GroupPage />` I'm setting the current group Id in setCurrentId and directing it to the `<CreateGroupForm />`. In `<CreateGroupForm />` I'm checking if currentId matches the one with the already existed group. And by useEffect I'm populating those values in form fields.

```
const CreateGroupForm = ({currentId, setCurrentId}) => {

    const [groupData, setGroupData] = useState({
        groupName: ''
    })

    const group = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.groups.groups.find((grp) => grp._id === currentId) : null)

    console.log(group) // null
    console.log(currentId) // undefined

    useEffect(() => {
        if(group) setGroupData(group)
    }, [group])

    return (
        <div>
            <MainForm>
                <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <h1>{ currentId ? 'Editing' : 'Creating'} a Group:</h1>
                    <label htmlFor="Group Name">Your Group Namee: </label>
                    <input type="text" value={groupData.groupName} onChange={(e) => setGroupData({ ...groupData, groupName: e.target.value })} />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </MainForm>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateGroupForm
```

What is happening:

On clicking the Edit button, the form fields are not populating with the group content.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get `null` and `undefined` for `group` and `currentId`?

Comment: @DánielBoros Yes, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to pass setStates between its children. I recommend you to create callback functions in your appMain, and pass that functions to your GroupPage and CreateGroupForm components. When you call those functions inside the components your functions will change your currentIdState in the appMain. Changing the state of currentId in your appMain the components will recive the new state of currentId

Comment: How do I change the currentIdState in a function?

Comment: Only when clicking on the Edit button, I want to send my current group Id in setCurrentId state. Not sure how this is wrong.

Comment: `const changingCurrentId = useCallback((id) => {
    setCurrentId(id);
  }, [currentId]);`

And pass that function to your component, intead of passing the setState